# html. Один из элементов растянуть по высоте родителя

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, как не меняя эту структуру html (только на css), сделать чтоб flex-elem растягивался по высоте родителя?

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-elem">+</div>
  <span class="text1">some text 1</span>
  <span class="text2">some text 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Как в конечном итоге должен выглядеть `flex-elem`, и как он должен позиционироваться, относительно других элементов в `.wrapper`?

Comment: `height: 100%;` для .flex-elem?

Comment: Если у родителя не фиксированная высота и отталкиваться вся конструкция будет от остальных блоков, можно воспользоваться абсолютной позицией и отступом. Это если данный блок статичен, если же нет, тогда вам на помощь придет JS. Примеры накидаю, если будет нужно. Еще можно все это дело превратить в таблицу через стили, но, это уже по ситуации нужно смотреть.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Спасибо за предложенную помощь. Решение я уже выложил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть не самый красиывый вариант получился, но решил это так:

```css
.wrapper{
  position:relative; /* чтоб .flex-elem absolute срабатывал относительно .wrapper */
  padding-left:15px;
  background:pink;

}
.flex-elem{
  position:absolute;
  top:0; /*приклеиваем к сторонам */
  left:0; /*приклеиваем к сторонам */
  bottom:0; /*приклеиваем к сторонам */
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-elem">+</div>
  <span class="text1"> ПЕРВЫЙ SPAN Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой</span>
  <span class="text2">ВТОРОЙ SPAN В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Значение свойства **height** можно задавать в процентах, и тогда оно будет интерпретироваться как доля высоты элемента родителя. Кроме того может быть полезным включить обтекание текстом для растянутого элемента, чтобы оставшийся текст расположился бы сбоку от плюсика, он не заползёт под сам блок, просто потому, что он уже растянут максимально.

```css
/* основное */
.flex-elem {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

/* для оформления */
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
}
.flex-elem {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-elem">+</div>
  <span class="text1">some text 1</span>
  <span class="text2">some text 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: При таком варианте `.flex-elem` не будет растягиваться, если у родителя не задана точная высота

Comment: Да, действительно.. приходится задавать высоту для wrapper